# Kotlin - Retrofit request using RxJava gives null response

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, retrofit, rx-android

I'm trying to get news from Guardian API. I'm getting null response, everything is below. I'm using Kotlin, Retrofit and RxJava. I know that there are some miscalled variables/objects but I will change them when I will get rid of that problem.

**Retrofit interface**

```
@get:GET("search?api-key=test")
    val news:Observable<News>
```

**Retrofit client**

```
val instance : Retrofit
    get() {
        if (myInstance == null) {
            myInstance = Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("https://content.guardianapis.com/")
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                    .build()
        }
        return myInstance!!
    }
```

**And function where I'm loading data**

```
private fun loadUrlData() {
        compositeDisposable.add(jsonApi.news
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe{news -> displayData(news)})
    }
```

**JSON example**

```
{  
   response:{  
      status:"ok",
      userTier:"developer",
      total:2063064,
      startIndex:1,
      pageSize:10,
      currentPage:1,
      pages:206307,
      orderBy:"newest",
      results:[  
         {  
            id:"politics/2018/sep/24/keir-starmer-labour-does-not-rule-out-remaining-in-eu",
            type:"article",
            sectionId:"politics",
            sectionName:"Politics",
            webPublicationDate:"2018-09-24T18:57:48Z",
            webTitle:"Keir Starmer: Labour does not rule out remaining in EU as option",
            webUrl:"https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2018/sep/24/keir-starmer-labour-does-not-rule-out-remaining-in-eu",
            apiUrl:"https://content.guardianapis.com/politics/2018/sep/24/keir-starmer-labour-does-not-rule-out-remaining-in-eu",
            isHosted:false,
            pillarId:"pillar/news",
            pillarName:"News"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

**Model class**

```
data class News( val status: String, val userTier: String, val total: Int, val startIndex: Int, val pageSize: Int, val currentPage: Int, val pages: Int, val orderBy: String, val results: List<Result>)
```

I suppose that the problem is with the last function or with the interface but I can't find the solution.

Comment: How does your data model (`News`) in Kotlin look like?

Comment: data class News(
        val status: String, 
        val userTier: String, 
        val total: Int, 
        val startIndex: Int, 
        val pageSize: Int, 
        val currentPage: Int, 
        val pages: Int, 
        val orderBy: String, 
        val results: List<Result>
)

Comment: Yeah, that's the issue. :-)
Your JSON has an outer node (`response`) and if you're trying to return a `News` you won't get it, because RetroFit can't map the JSON to the `News` class.
Add an outer class called `Response` that holds a field called `response` that is of type `News`, that should fix it.

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't see that response is another node. As you said I created class Response where I have constructor with News object. Everything works fine now. Thanks again :)

Comment: No problem - I'll add it as an answer, so you can close the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issues lies within your data model class.

Your JSON has an outer node (`response`) and if you're trying to return a `News` you won't get it, because `Retrofit` can't map the JSON to the `News` class. Add an outer class called `Response` that holds a field called response that is of type `News`, that should fix it.

Like so:

```
class Response(val response: News)
```

Note: I haven't added `data` in front of the class as you don't necessarily need it. The `data` keyword just adds some extra things for you automatically, like `toString()`, `equals()` and `hashCode()`, but unless you're actually using them for anything I wouldn't recommend adding the `data` keyword as it's pretty useless then.